# Cycle through all applications, across workspaces

Tags: release-loki, display, keyboard-shortcuts, workspace

I am running Loki with 2 monitors. I have workspaces [only on my primary monitor](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2732/workspaces-seem-to-only-apply-to-the-primary-display-is-this-a-feature-or-a-bug/4295#4295).

Also cycling through opened applications with Alt+Tab, I can only cycle through application on that workspace: Is there an option to cycle through all applications, including the ones from other workspaces ?

Comment: There's an answer in [another post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2732/workspaces-seem-to-only-apply-to-the-primary-display-is-this-a-feature-or-a-bug/4295#4295) to solve the problem of workspace only on the primary monitor. I am still looking for an answer to the problem of cycling through opened applications with Alt+Tab on all workspaces !

Answer (score 3):

**Nope**, without custom scripting, the OS only supports switching between windows in a workspace ("Switch Windows" in `Settings > Keyboard`) and switching between workspaces (`org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings cycle-workspaces-next`), but not apps across all workspaces.

What you can do, however, is set **"Show All Windows"** in `Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts` (also `org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings expose-all-windows`), which will display every open window across all workspaces so you can choose the window you want.

Comment: _\*sigh\*_ Still seems to be the case in 2023, although I haven't tested with elementaryOS 7 yet.