# How to disable the empty workspace that appears when switching between them?

Tags: workspace

The only thing that's preventing me from using other workspaces (besides the main one) is that I can't switch between them properly.

1. ALT+TAB will only switch between apps in the current workspace.
2. Super+Left/Right will iterate through an empty workspace, which is annoying.

Can I change any of these options?

Comment: The first question has already an answer here: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7749/cycle-through-all-applications-across-workspaces?rq=1

Comment: What do you mean by iterating through an empty workspace? You can put applications there as well and it will no more be empty…

Comment: So I guess the first option is off the table, thanks. Also, what I mean is that if I put applications there it'll create a third workspace which will be empty.

Comment: You can disable dynamic workspaces under `org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior`, set `dynamic_workspaces` to `false`. Nevertheless, there is no "empty workspace" created unless you put something there.

Comment: Great! it kinda did the job. How can I set this fixed number? It always creates 4 workspaces.

Comment: [What would it be for you the proper way to switch between the workspaces?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10899/170)

Comment: The problem is not switching between workspaces, as I'm familiar with the shortcut keys. What I'm missing is a way to switch between all open apps regardless of the workspace they're in. Like Mac, and it even works like that on Windows. Essentially, I'd like the CTRL-TAB shortcuts to switch between all apps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable dynamic workspaces:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior dynamic-workspaces false
```

You can set the number of workspaces wanted to NUMBER:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences num-workspaces NUMBER
```

(Nevertheless, even if you use dynamic workspaces, there are actually no "empty workspaces"…).

Comment: Thank you so much! This answered my other question about how to get apps to stop opening in a new workspace. (http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10645/how-to-delete-workspaces)

Comment: The solution has changed. Use the following command instead: "gsettings set org.gnome.mutter dynamic-workspaces false". The command to set the number of workspaces continues to be the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

The title of your question was a bit contradictory (therefore I have edited it a bit), as there were multiple questions involved; you seem to prefer to disable the workspaces but also to give them a second chance if a better way to switch them was to be presented to you.

As you have selected a definitive answer, I imagine that the most important part was how to disable them.

But there is also the other question in the question body, as you say:

> The only thing that's preventing me from using other workspaces
> (besides the main one) is that I can't switch between them properly.
>
> ...
>
> Can I change any of these options?

***What would it be for you the proper way to switch between the workspaces?***

The range of possibilities is large: see [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1479/170).

To simply cycle them, there is also <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

To display them all and their windows I like <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. Only the windows of the selected workspace are displayed in this way (unlike  <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> which shows all windows, including conkys, which is not too clever; that shortcut can be edited - I changed it to  <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> myself).

The same can be achieved with a hot corner (e.g. 'Settings-Desktop-Hot corners', and setting down-left corner to Multitasking view.)

When the multitasking view is displayed, **the mouse or touchpad scroll** will switch the workspaces too.

The use of the hot-corner and the wheel/scroll allows to **switch workspaces only with the mouse or touchpad**.

That is very useful for me in selecting/closing windows especially when the dock is set to auto-hide.

I use workspaces mostly when I run an application that I don't need too often (e.g. a script in a terminal that I need to monitor only rarely), or when I need to [cycle only the windows of the same application](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10722/170).

Any application gets its own separate workspace if set to fullscreen with <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>.

You can edit a lot of shortcuts under *'Settings-Keyboard-Shortcuts-Workspaces'*.

[image]