# How to remove second workspace?

Tags: settings, desktop, workspace

Whenever I launch a Steam game, accidentally press the Windows button and the right arrow key, or something else, it takes me to the second workspace, which comes default with elementary.

I want to delete it, but I cant find anything on how I can do this.

I only want one workspace. What do I do?

**EDIT:** Oh dear, this is a duplicate question. This has the answer I was looking for: [How to disable the empty workspace that appears when switching between them?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10013/how-to-disable-the-empty-workspace-when-switching-between-them)

Answer (score 4):

Empty workspaces are deleted automatically when you stop viewing them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to remove workspaces other than to move or close the app that is sitting in it. To prevent new ones from being created you just need to avoid "activating" one with the keystroke.