# Are there different ways to create new workspaces in Loki?

Tags: workspace

Installed Loki a few days ago, and the biggest headache I've had was figuring out how to use the multiple workspaces feature. From what I read, Super-0 is supposed to create a new workspace, but that doesn't seem to work. In my keyboard settings, it says Super-End is the keyboard shortcut for doing that. But that doesn't work either.

What DOES seem to work is that if I open an application in a blank workspace, a new workspace is automatically created. So is that the only way, or is there another way?

Answer (score 5):

- With dynamic workspaces enabled (which is default in elementary OS), you cannot create workspaces explicitely but

  - a new empty workspace is created by switching to the right of the rightmost existing workspace or
  - a new workspace is created by moving a window right to the rightmost existing workspace.
- If you disable dynamic workspaces (via the command line here):

  ```
  gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior dynamic-workspaces false
  ```

  you can set the number of workspaces wanted to NUMBER:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences num-workspaces NUMBER
  ```

  In this case, you can create new workspace by changing the number on-the-fly. For instance, you could create a script that does that and assign a custom shortcut to this script in *System Settings*/*Keyboard* (*Shortcuts* tab).

cf., [How to disable the empty workspace that appears when switching between them?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10013/how-to-disable-the-empty-workspace-that-appears-when-switching-between-them/10014#10014)

Comment: Whoa, that is very cool. Thanks for sharing! This is definitely what OP is looking for.

Comment: It is indeed cool and I'd like to try that. What do I need to do to create the script?

Comment: these are not really a script, only some commands to be executed in a terminal window

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of many keyboard shortcuts, starting with the ones for managing windows and workspaces.

---

**WINDOWS**

> Close

```
Alt + f4
```

> Unmaximize

```
Alt + f5
```

> Toggle Maximized

```
Windows Key + Up Arrow
```

> Minimize

```
Windows Key + H
```

> Tile Left

```
Windows Key + Ctrl + Left Arrow
```

> Tile Right

```
Windows Key + Ctrl + Right Arrow
```

> Switch Windows

```
Alt + Tab
```

> Switch Windows Backwards

```
Shift + Alt + Tab
```

> Window Overview

```
Windows Key + W
```

> Show All Windows

```
Windows Key + A
```

---

**WORKSPACES**

> Show Workspace Switcher

```
Windows Key + Down Arrow
```

> Switch to First

```
Windows Key + Home
```

> Switch to New

```
Windows Key + End
```

> Switch to Workspace 1

```
Windows Key + 1
```

> Switch to Workspace 2

```
Windows Key + 2
```

> Switch to Workspace 3

```
Windows Key + 3
```

> Switch to Workspace 4

```
Windows Key + 4
```

> Switch to Workspace 5

```
Windows Key + 5
```

> Switch to Workspace 6

```
Windows Key + 6
```

> Switch to Workspace 7

```
Windows Key + 7
```

> Switch to Workspace 8

```
Windows Key + 8
```

> Switch to Workspace 9

```
Windows Key + 9
```

> Switch to Left

```
Windows Key + Left Arrow
```

> Switch to Right

```
Windows Key + Right Arrow
```

---

**SCREENSHOTS**

> Take a Screenshot

```
Print Screen
```

> Save Screenshot to Clipboard

```
Ctrl + Print Screen
```

> Save Screenshot of a Window

```
Alt + Print Screen
```

> Save Window-screenshot to Clipboard

```
Ctrl + Alt + Print Screen
```

---

Now, with all of that said, I prefer using the workspaces feature using

```
Windows Key + Tab

Shift + Windows Key + Tab
```

to navigate around. Don't forget you also have a blue square icon on the bottom left for multitasking view.

Comment: Thanks for the information! So, [Windows] End goes to the new (rightmost) workspace but doesn't create a new workspace, I gather? Is there a way to create a new workspace besides opening an application in the rightmost workspace?

Comment: Yes, I use Windows + Tab, I believe that is what you are looking for. It will create a new workspace before it loops back around the list of open Workspaces. Try it out and see is that is what you are looking for.   --Just noticed I forgot to put these into the hotkey list. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an aside for future reference, if you are using multiple displays:
The primary display must be turned on in order for multiple workspaces to be created. If it is not, switch the primary display to any currently used display.